# "It sounds weird to me to not see a subject in the sentence"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, negation, grammatical-roles, infinitive-constructions

I am writing a comment about a sentence's grammaticality and I feel uncertain about these options that came to mind:

> It (the sentence) sounds weird to me to not see a subject in the sentence.

I thought this would work because (for me) to not see a subject seems to work as a whole. But it also doesn't sound very natural to me. Does it work? If so what grammatical function does "(for me) to not see a subject" serve? A complement? An adjunct?

> It sounds weird to me to not have a subject in the sentence.

This sounds more natural to me as "to not have a subject in the sentence" modifies the subject. The subject "it" seems to be a dummy subject here with the real subject being "to not have a subject in the sentence." Does it work?

> The sentence sounds weird to me to not have a subject in it.

This one sounds fine to me too, but I wonder what function "to not have a subject in it" serves.

Comment: Try ‘It sounds weird to me not to see a subject …’ and you’re one step better off.

Comment: Do all three of *“to not have a subject”* and *“not to have a subject”* and *“to have no subject”* sound equally weird to you? If not, which ones are which? Would *“having no subject”* and *“not having a subject”* both sound weird, or just one or neither?

Comment: How can not **SEEING** a subject **SOUND** weird???

Comment: Are you worried about having two phrases with "to" next to each other? That's grammatically fine although you could consider rephrasing or reordering. It depends what part of the sentence you want to emphasise - whether it's personal to you, or "to me" is just a minor qualification.

Comment: It would be so much simpler to say _A sentence without a subject sounds weird to me_...

Answer (score 3):

This is a case of **it-extraposition** (see [this explanation from UC Berkeley](https://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/%7Ekay/bcg/extrap.html)).

As you noted, the real subject of the sentence is the infinitival verb phrase starting with "to not have". But due to it-extraposition, the subject here gets replaced by "it" and moved to the end of the sentence.

Edit: For this reason, "The sentence sounds weird to me to not have a subject in it" is ungrammatical, because it-extraposition requires the word "it," and none of the other forms of extraposition (see the link above) allow for an infinitival verb phrase.

"It (the sentence) sounds weird to me to not see a subject in the sentence" is also incorrect. The "it" there is just a placeholder used for extraposition, not a pronoun with an antecedent. So "it" cannot refer to "the sentence."

Comment: The sentence cannot be an extraposition if the *it* in the first example refers to *the sentence* as indicated by the original Poster. It is just an ungrammatical sentence. [If, however, the *it* was a meaningless dummy subject, that would be just as described in your answer]. And what about the OP's last example?

Comment: But of course it doesn't refer to _the sentence._ And nobody should worry about whether it's an adjunct. It's a subject complement clause extraposed by rule, and the _it_ is a dummy with no reference. The sentence is already identified as the locus in the extraposed subject. And no, the last sentence is wildly ungrammatical in _the it_.

Comment: @JohnLawler I just realized I made a typo in the last sentence. I meant for the "it" to refer to "the sentence" and while tweaking the sentences I accidentally left an extra definite article in there. It's supposed to be _"The sentence sounds weird to me to not have a subject in it."_

Comment: @desmo I edited my answer to address this issue! The answer is that your last sentence is ungrammatical, precisely because it-extraposition requires the word "it" to be used.

Comment: You could use a gerund clause but not an infinitive there: _The sentence sounds weird to me, not having a subject in it._

Answer (score 1):

OP's text...

> 1: *It (the sentence) sounds weird to me to not see a subject in the sentence.*

...is *idiomatically* unlikely because as [this usage chart shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It%20is%20important%20to%20not%2CIt%20is%20important%20not%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), we much prefer *sounds weird **not to** [do something]* over ***...to not** [do it]*.

But that's just a stylistic choice. The real problem is *syntactic*. If we remove OP's "parenthetical" inclusion *(**the sentence**),* AND remove the syntactically irrelevant adverbial element ***to me***, AND resolve the semantic clash between *sounding* and *seeing*, we're left with...

> 2: *It looks weird to not see a subject in the sentence*

Which is fine. But that's because the first word is the ***existential "it"*** - it's most definitely ***not*** a pronoun referencing anything like ***the sentence***. If it *was*, then we could just replace it by the actual noun...

> 3: *The sentence looks weird [to not | not to] see a subject [in the sentence].*

But #3 is syntactic garbage - regardless of the ***to not / not to*** choice, and regardless of whether we remove the unnecessary  second reference to ***the sentence***.